# Android - How to parse String to Number with both comma or point as decimal separator

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I need a function that can parse both 1,123.12 and 1.123,12 to 1123.12
There are 3 sources for the numbers I use, 1 will always come in US format, 1 will always come in PT_BR (1.123,12) and the third may come in any format depending on the locale of the device how can I correctly parse all of them?

Edit: I don't know which way the number is formatted, I need a function that can receive any of those formats and parse it correctly. Maybe what I need is a way to test in which format is a string that represents a number. Something that will receive "1.123,12" and say that is "PT_BR" and receive 1,123.12 and say that is "US". But I have no idea how to do this especially how to make something like this wok for any location.

Comment: maybe numberformat can help! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: numberformat can't help because I don't know in which format i'm getting the number.

Comment: I'm using:
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.parse(string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the locale of the environment. There ain't exist anything like a locale in the context of a string, it's the exact opposite: **the meaning of the string depends on the locale**. There are cases where you can guess the number represented by a string (like the ones you posted) but what about 123,456 for example? It's ambiguous, so no library can do this work. Obviously if you impose some constraint (for example the number must have two decimal digits) you will be able to easily write your own parser, but without such a conventions it's simply impossible

Comment: I was getting to that conclusion just before I read your answer. I will have to format every number as it comes from the sources, in that point i know which format it is. It's going to be a long day!

Answer (score 3):

US:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = nf.parse("1,123.12");
```

Brazilian Portuguese:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-BR"));
Number number = nf.parse("1.123,12");
```

Default locale:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number number = nf.parse("1123.12");
```

Comment: But I don't know where they are coming from. If your US function receives 1.123,12 it won't work. Is there a way to know what is the locale of a string?

Comment: @Jack Great answer, Thank you!